# Any way to improve speed of BitmapFactory.decodeStream()?

Tags: android

Obviously this is an expensive/time-consuming operation. Any way to improve this?

```
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream) new URL(
                                            someUrl).getContent());
```

I'm guessing there's really no way to avoid this relatively intense operation, but wanted to see if anyone had any tweaks they could recommend (aside from caching the actual bitmap, which for whatever reasons simply isn't relevant here)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't need the full resolution you can have it only read ever nth pixel, where n is a power of 2. You do this by setting `inSampleSize` on an [Options](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html) object which you pass to `BitmapFactory.decodeFile`. You can find the sample size by just reading the meta-data from the file in a first pass by setting `inJustDecodeBounds` on the `Options` object. Aside from that - no, I don't think there's an easy way to make to go any faster than it already does.

Edit, example:

```
    Options opts = new Options();
    // Get bitmap dimensions before reading...
    opts.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, opts);
    int width = opts.outWidth;
    int height = opts.outHeight;
    int largerSide = Math.max(width, height);
    opts.inJustDecodeBounds = false; // This time it's for real!
    int sampleSize = ??; // Calculate your sampleSize here
    opts.inSampleSize = sampleSize;
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, opts);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Can you elaborate on " You can find the sample size by just reading the meta-data from the file in a first pass by setting inJustDecodeBounds on the Options object." a little more? Maybe with an example?

Comment: I have added a code example. If your sampleSize is two, then width and height will be halved. If it's 4 it will be a fourth and so on.

Comment: Ended up doing this: (most of it taken from fedorvlasov.lazylist) https://gist.github.com/1589700