# Loading Bitmaps from url too slow

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I am loading about 10 Bitmaps from a Database, but it might be a few more in the future.

This takes in total about 3 seconds, which I would like to improve, as the user needs to wait until the loading has finished. (The loading happens in an `AsyncTask`)

Here is my code:

```
 Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
```

This is within a loop where I load a JSONArray from a DB, including this image (url is a valid, direct link to the image).

I recorded the milliseconds it takes to load everything, about 350ms for one iteration, but about 300ms is just the conversion.

Is there any way to improve this? Like not creating a new Bitmap-Object everytime?

Comment: Bitmap? Over network? Use compressed images.

Comment: I have no control over the images or the input.

Comment: Give this a try: [Any way to improve speed of BitmapFactory.decodeStream()?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8805564/2558882)

Comment: You can thread each Bitmap so you can download various simultaneously and decode them also in parallel. I'm afraid that given your situation you cannot do much more. Ask for changing how the images are stored, because that way (Bitmap inside JSON) is inherently slow.

Comment: @vikram thanks for the link, but it hardly reduces the time the loading takes - but I know now, that´s it´s mainly the network, and not the conversion itself

Comment: Well, it was worth a try. Hope you figure this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you add a cache feature? When you load the image, you'll attempt to load it from cache first. If the image is there, you should have it instantly.

I am using [`LRUCache`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/util/LruCache.html) from compatibility package.

Besides that, loading images from a database will always be time and resource consuming. You have to lookup first, fetch the data and then perform decoding. Depending on data type persisted and size of image, it's normal to have these delays. For this reason, why not persist the images on SD card or anywhere in your app files structure? I am using [`DiskLRUCache`](https://github.com/JakeWharton/DiskLruCache) for this.

**Edit**: I noticed now that the source of your images is a network service. That's even better: construct a two layered cache: memory cache and disk-cache.

So getting an image will do:

1. Check if image is in memory: yes, you have it instantly.
2. Check if image in on sdcard/app file structure: yes, you have it almost instantly
3. Download the image from network. But even here you can do some improvement, if you have access to that service. On server side use an API to resize the images to your need. Cache those resized images on server side as well. That way you'll optimize both download speed and client app memory. Or if you don't have access to that service, build your own proxy service that does this on-the-fly resizing and call that service instead.

Comment: there are over a hundred images, and i only need a few of these - but i might need different ones the next time i load images. But Caching looks like it might be an improvement

Comment: Well, `LRU` stands for "Least Recent Used". That means the more you use an image, the less you'll download/load from storage. Just careful on how you setup the `LRUCache`. Give it a percentage of max memory usage.

Comment: Added more suggestions to my answer.

Comment: Hello, I'm using LRUCache with the DiskLRUCache. Could you give me any suggestion?? here is my question 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49800894/how-can-i-use-both-disklrucachediskcache-and-lrucachememorycache'

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that every connection is handled by itself this means every image creates a new TCP connection gets the data and then closes the connection again.

You can try to use threads to load multiple images at once. Most time is lost while creating the connections and is you serialize the requests you will wait every time. If you use threads you can decrease the complete time for image loading as the connection creation is parallelized.

Another option would be to use a dedicated HTTP client library. This can handle connections better as they open the TCP connection only once and then send multiple requests over this single connection. The overhead for the TCP connection is then only once.

Comment: could you post an example/a link to an example for loading with threads without closing the connection?

Comment: @BenjaminSchwalb read a tutorial about threading (e.g. [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html)).

Comment: Threading itself is not the problem, just the part with not opening the connection everytime - `BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream()` here i open the connection explicitly - how would I need to change this?

Comment: Use a library like [HTTP client](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/index.html) from Apache.